# How to meditate after an adrenaline rush or exertion?

Tags: training, meditation

I always find it difficult to concentrate and empty my mind when I have just had argument with someone or have done very tough physical training.

What are good pre-meditation techniques to find the calm in your mind and just keep it there during meditation even though your body has adrenalin rush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember a passage from Way of the Peaceful Warrior in which Socrates asks a hippie, "Do you meditate?" like it was a dirty secret. It always stuck with me because it seems like this is how 90% of people treat meditation: as a dirty secret, done behind closed and locked doors, out of sight of other people.

The approach of pre-meditation techniques and adrenaline rush disturbing meditation? They're wrong-headed thoughts. That is, if you're having that much trouble, ***you're not meditating***!

Adrenaline rush is a response to fear; the endorphin rush from exertion is different, though the feeling is similar. There are only two things that people really fear: what happened in the past (depression), and what they believe will happen in the future (anxiety). In this very moment, there is no time to be afraid. We are alive in this moment, we can not change the past, and we can not control the future. So of what on earth is there to be afraid?

In this very instance, ask yourself these questions:

1. What is going on?
2. Where are you?
3. What time is it?

It was amazing, but these three stupid questions were all it took for my life to take an entirely new meaning. *What's going on?* There's always something happening, there's always something going on; everything and everywhere, there is life happening all about us and we are simply one small part of that overall world; there is never nothing going on. *Where am I?* I'm right here; my body may be at my desk, or going through some rote activity, but I am right here, living and experiencing what is around me. *What time is it?* It's now; I can't change the past and I can't control the future; the only thing that matters is what's happening this moment.

Once you can see those same conclusions in your own way, you'll understand meditation. It's not some event, your mind doesn't need to be quieted. It just is quiet, and you just are experiencing life. The more amazing part? Harmony. The same silly concept everyone was prattling on about in zen groups and buddhist clubs since high school? It's the simplest thing on earth – care, but don't be consumed.

You don't need meditative techniques or tricks. Just let go. Be always in a meditative state and you won't need to clear your head; it simply will be clear.

I heard a story once:

A monk walks by the side of a river. From nowhere, a stone is thrown and strikes the monk in the side of the head and he collapses to the ground. A moment later, he gets up and without looking around or tending to his wound, he continues walking in the direction he was headed. A man who witnessed the whole thing runs after him and asks, "Why did you not try to find who threw the stone at you?"

The monk replied: "The stone is in the past."

Answer (score 2):

For training you never want to go from very physical to sedentary. Always have a cool down and a stretch, this allows your body to adjust to the changing physical and energy demands and for your nervous systems to switch over (sympathetic/parasympathetic).

When I'm stressed, due to work or an argument, I personally like to go out into nature if possible. The sun, air and sounds always calm me down. If I can't get out into nature (i.e. at work) and the sun is out I go outside and look at the sun with my eyes closed for five or so minutes.

We all will have different forms of mediation, different things that our minds and bodies will respond to. What makes you comfortable, where are you at peace? If possible try to find those thoughts or places. Don't cling onto thoughts and emotions, instead let them flow over you.

Breath consistently, focus on your breathing. Take air in though the nose, exhale though the mouth and reverse. Keep it a slow and steady pace, developing into a rhythm. I find that if I focus on breathing with my eyes closed that it clears my mind before a test or belt exam.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent answer here (http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/202/65) to "How to lower heart rate at will".

Essentially: soft humming. This will resemble softly chanting "om" or humming a lullaby.

stslavik has the rest of the answer: meditation doesn't stop when you get off the floor.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you get to Carnegie Hall: practice.

I'm not exactly a serious student of meditation, but for about a year I had about twenty minutes between a exercise class at the University gym and the beginning of the Akindo Club practice session. I started spending the time meditating; sitting cross-legged or in half-lotus or even in seiza, and just breathing with deliberation. At first I had a very hard time because my body was keyed up, but after a while I became more adept at slowing my breathing, lowering my heartrate, and putting aside the cares of the day.